# \hyphenation{ } in a part of text

Tags: hyphenation

Is it possible to make `\hyphenation{ }` only in one chapter or small text?
Not the whole text but only in small pieces of text.

Maybe it is possible to make a new language and use different hyphenations. In old form of languages and citations or in artificial languages.

Comment: Are you looking to limit the scope of hyphenation break points (set up via a `\hyphenation` command) to a certain part of your document, or are you looking to disable/enable hyphenation entirely for the parts in question?

Comment: limit in part of text. but limits in few pieces of text. limit the part of the text, but not only one but several different parts of the text the same kind of another hyphenations. turn on/off my own hyphenations in small diferent part of documents

Comment: a simple experiment seems to me to show that the effect of \hyphenation commands is remains whatever you do; you can set it inside a group (or even inside a box) and it will still be there after the group or box closes.  i would invent a new "language" with its own hyphenation, but that's a pretty heavy undertaking.

Comment: what i can use my previous hyphenation in next/other pages?

Comment: You are supposed to be able to have several hyphenation patterns loaded and switch between them using `\setlanguage`.  I know that Luatex allows you to manipulate the patterns in each language during processing.  I'll leave details to someone who knows something substantial about how to actually do this.

Comment: @jak - I'm afraid my earlier question may not have been sufficiently clear. I'm still uncertain as to what you're trying to achieve: (i) Turn off hyphenation entirely in a part of the document, or (ii) change the hyphenation patterns in a part of the document. Please advise.

Comment: ii)

and second trouble. What i can change, and change back to prewious hyphenation

Comment: My english is horrible. ;-( sorry

Answer (score 3):

In TeX hyphenation of text is dependent on the language in force, which technically is the current value of the integer register `\language`. Technically hyphenation rules are loaded by selecting the language (setting the register to some number representing it) and then loading a set of hyphenation patterns via the `\pattern` command. This is one of the commands that in traditional TeX can only be used while format generation is possible, so normally the languages are already predefined in the format that is loaded  at start.

On top of those base rules one can use the `\hyphenation` command which alters the rules of the "current" language, i.e., in a multi-language document one first have to switch to the right language and then give the desired `\hyphenation` execptions. From that point on they stay available for this language, so whenever the language is select they will be used.

So to cut the long story short: yes you need to prepare several languages (with identical patterns) then add the desired `\hyphenation` exceptions to some of them and then switch between them as needed. The Babel system has a method of providing new languages but this is not daily user stuff, so you will need to dig a bit to see how this works.

Comment: ok I start new question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109779/how-i-can-add-my-own-language/109788?noredirect=1#109788