# How I can add my own language

Tags: languages, hyphenation, ligatures

I wrote an artificial language (conlang).

What I can add my own language in LaTeX? Conlang has more letters than English (utf8 and some ligatures) and specyfic hyphenations.

Where is simple/minimal tutorial or example.

No cóż, skoro i tak zamknięto pytanie nie dając odpowiedzi nie wiem czy jest sens go zadawać w tym gronie.

Comment: Without more specific information about the language it's difficult to give any advice.

Comment: We should not be too quick closing questions but rather give the OP the chance to enhance it.

Comment: This is question. Where is small example what I can add my own language to project.

Comment: @egreg look down. 2 words, hyphenation. You don't read comments

Comment: What does "two words" mean? I can't understand.

Comment: @egreg look down.

Answer (score 1):

Simple tutorial for words hyphenation? I am afraid, it would be a problem. It was Frank Liang's Ph.D. thesis, see, e.g., http://tug.org/docs/liang/

However, if your artificial language has got regular hyphenation rules, there is a possiblility of making patterns manually.

**Edit** On ordinary hyphenation is simple: e.g.

\hyphenation{A-nu-sia Bor-zo-bo-ha-ta}

Comment: No problem. Tell me what i can add simple language and one hyphenation.

example:

all world in my language

`Będzie dobrze`

all hyphenation:

`{bed-zie dobr-ze}`

tell me what I can to do this.

Comment: A simple hyphenation, or a simple hyphenation patterns? The latter needs iniTeX...

Comment: simple hyphenation utf-8 no pattern. My lang have only 2 words/

Comment: @jak I have just updated my answer. Do you really need only hyphenation of two (or a few) words?

Comment: Two words is for example. Importatn is turn off and turn on hyphenation, fonts etc. similar language.  Chodzi o to by móc zrobic nowy język. Pisze książke i co chwila mam tekst/akapit w jednym języku a co chwila znów wracam do głównego języka. Musiałbym za każdym razem zamieszczac ten sam zestaw dzielenia wyrazów, specyficznych fontów itp. To własnie jest to pytanie. Jak zrobić nowy język. Jkis taki najmniejszy możliwy przykład jak to wykonać.